# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null - Google Карта

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, google-maps

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.216305, 28.392368),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

```
  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("maps.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var photo = markers[i].getAttribute("photo");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>"+"<img src="+photo+" width=200 height=100><br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });`
```

Comment: Проверьте XML документ на валидность.

Comment: спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`downloadUrl("/maps.php", function(data) {`
- не верно указана директория.**"maps.php"**

Comment: Это что - ответ или пояснение? Если пояснение - то удалите его и вставьте в свой вопрос.

Comment: изменил, на ответ разобрался сам.